# Fechas en firebase android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, firebase, datetime

¡Hola a todos! :)

Espero me puedan ayudar. Tengo una aplicación en JAVA Android Studio, en la cual quiero comparar 2 fechas (una es creada cuando registro a un usuario y la otra es la fecha actual).
En resumen es para corroborar la fecha del vencimiento de una suscripción y no he logrado poder comparar las fechas de ninguna forma.

Dejo el código de como he creado las fechas al momento del registro:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    int year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    n0w= year+"-"+(month+1)+"-"+(day);//fecha actual
    expiration = year+"-"+(month+1)+"-"+(day+10);// fecha de vencimiento de prueba.
```

En realidad la única de estas fechas que subo a firebase es "expiration", la cual quiero comparar cada vez que el usuario abre la aplicación. (Espero me entiendan)
Sé que en este ejemplo los estoy enviando como un String. Pero como dije anteriormente, no he logrado poder comparar ambas fechas y mi código a sufrido una infinidad de cambios.

Espero me entiendan y me logren ayudar!
De antemano, muy agradecido. <3

Comment: Hola. Faltan detalles en tu pregunta. Hablas de dos fechas, y lo esencial es saber de qué modo obtienes esas dos fechas. ¿Las obtienes correctamente? Una vez hecho eso, dinos en qué formato las obtienes. A partir de ahí, se podrán hacer las comparaciones.

Comment: Hola, Gracias por tu pronta respuesta. 
En el código publicado obtengo las 2 fechas en formato yyyy-MM-dd pero no como una fecha, si no como un String, y como comento también, la única fecha que guardo en firebse es "expiration" que es la que luego quiero poder comparar con la fecha actual del dispositivo cada vez que el usuario abra la aplicación y ver si aún tiene vigencia su suscripción.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convertir las fechas a la clase LocalDate y restarlas.

Ejemplo:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

LocalDate today = LocalDate.now(); //Obtenemos fecha actual

LocalDate expiration = sdf.parse("04/12/2020");

long diff = expiration.getTime() - today.getTime();
```

Si sale que diff es 0 o negativa es que ya ha caducado la subscripción.

Answer (score 0):

Gracias por sus respuestas :)

Logré realizar los que queria, quizás no de la mejor manera, pero funciona :D

El código que me funcionó fue:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            int year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            int month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            int day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

            String n0w= year+"-"+(month+1)+"-"+(day);

            //OBTENER FECHA DE CADUCIDAD

            SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy", Locale.getDefault());
            Calendar calendar1 = Calendar.getInstance();
            Calendar calendar2 = Calendar.getInstance();
            Date date1 = null;
            try {
                date1 = dateFormat.parse(n0w);
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Date date2 = null;
            try {
                date2 = dateFormat.parse(user.getFpago());
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            calendar1.setTime(date1);
            calendar2.setTime(date2);
```

Las cuales luego comparo con el método "compareTo"

Muchas Gracias!